# XPath function selectNodes does not wordk in Windows 8

Tags: xpath, windows-8, selectnodes

This small JavaScript snippet of code makes me mad since I installed Windows 8

```
xmlDoc=http_request.responseXML.documentElement;
var nodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes('/rfp_object/category');
```

Until that very moment everything worked fine for years, but now I meet trouble when using Windows 8.
The error says: The property or method selectNodes is not being supported by this object.

In Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Windows Vista it does what I was expecting. But under Windows 8 not. Even more peculiar is that it works fine in Development on an XP server, but not in production on Windows Server 2008.

Changing the selectNodes into getElementsByTagName('category') works great in this situation but is not an option, because I need to filter data in other occasions.

So what do I have to do, to make it work for Windows8 users like it used to work.
Any help will be higly appreciated.

Lourens

Answer (score 0):

I think IE 10 makes `responseXML` an IE XML DOM document while with earlier versions of IE it is an MSXML XML DOM document. The methods `selectSingleNode` and `selectNodes` are part of the MSXML DOM API but not of the IE DOM API. I don't think IE provides XPath support for its DOM documents so you will need to decide whether you want to convert the `responseXML` into an MSXML DOM document along the lines of

```
var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
doc.loadXML(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(http_request.responseXML));
```

to then use `selectNodes` on the `doc` variable or you will check whether the method IE offers like getElementsByTagName and querySelector allow you to find what you are looking for or you will need to check whether a Javascript implementation of XPath like https://github.com/ilinsky/xpath.js allows you to write the query you want.